# Android - Как проверять в onClickListener на название кнопки

Tags: java, android

Необходимо проверять по тексту кнопки выполнять инструкции, что-то вроде:

```
private final View.OnClickListener onClickMenu = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getResources().getText().toString()) {
            case '1':
                break;
            case '2':
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Но, оно ругается и что поставить в свиче?
Мне необходимо получать значение кнопки (getText) и выполнять действия.

Comment: Вас не смущает, что вы пытаетесь сравнить строку с символом в свитче?

Comment: Это для примера, отвечу, что пытался сравнивать и "1".

Comment: Какой текст ошибки возвращается?

Comment: Вообще ругается Cannot resolve method 'getText()';

Comment: строить бизнес-логику на контенте виджета - плохая затея.

Answer (score 2):

Настоятельно рекомендую пересмотреть такое решение, писать логику по контенту кпопки мягко говоря это **BadIdea**, а так вы немного не то написали в условии, `((Button) v).getText().toString()` и сравнивать необходимо: во-первых оператором `equals()`, а во-вторых со строкой `"String"`

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = ((Button) v).getText().toString()
        if (text.equals("2")) {

        } else if (text.equals("1")) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что стоит сперва привести то Вью к ТекстВью и потом уже реагировать на текст.

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            switch (tv.getText()) {
                case "1":
                    break;
                case "2":
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Если листерен вешаете не только на ТекстВью, реккомендую добавить проверку:

```
if (v instance of TextView)
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, сравнивать так строки можно с Java 7.  А для поддержки старых версий android такое не подойдёт..

Answer (score 0):

В switch-case проверьте по id кнопки :)

Comment: Нет, в данном случае мне нужно проверять по тексту на кнопке, поэтому вопрос задан именно так.:)